# web3.js function contract.once() not working on Kovan, but working on ganache

Tags: web3js, events, kovan

I am subscribing to an event (just once, queued after an update) of a contract to reload the data like this on my react frontend:

```js
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
instance.once(
    'Confirmation', 
    {filter: {sender, txnId}}, 
    () => dispatch(loadConfirmations(address, txnId))
)
```

it works perfectly when I am on my custom network with ganache. But when I try the same thing on Kovan, the callback does not fire. I tried other methods to subscribe to events, but none of them work. Getting past events works.

Web3 is provided via `window.ethereum` and I use metamask to inject the web3.

Any idea why I can't subscribe to events on Kovan like this?

Comment: What service are you using in order to connect to kovan (in other words, what is your node URL)?

Comment: I am using the injected provider from metamask

Comment: It probably doesn't support catching events (and fetching Historical data in general).